# Mongoose Data Types how to define multiple type values ? ESLint error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, eslint

I would like to define a filed 'lines' as an Array of values which can be of different types ( numbers or strings or boolean or dates )

when I try :

```
lines: [
{
  type: String,
  content: Mixed
}
```

]

I get an ESLint error error : Mixed is not defined

Should I write ?

```
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 ...
 lines: [
   Schema.Types.Mixed
 ]
```

Comment: I think type should be mixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to mongoose [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) you can use Mixed schema type as follows

```
var schema = new Schema({
ofMixed:    [Schema.Types.Mixed],
})

// example use

var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', schema);

m.ofMixed = [1, [], 'three', { four: 5 }];
m.save(callback);
```

Comment: Had you tried this? There is a notice to use `doc.markModified(path)` in documentation, but your example didn't mention about It.